# É possível dar extends em uma classe via reflection em java?

Tags: java, reflexão

Eu trabalho com uma API que muda o nome da classe e o nome das package sempre que uma atualização grande sai, porém, eu sou obrigado a dar suporte a versões antigas da API e pra isso eu uso reflections nesses casos, eu sempre trabalhei com `Class.forName()` e sempre consegui "driblar" esse problema dos nomes de classes e packages diferentes, porém me deparei com uma situação onde eu preciso criar uma classe X e estender uma classe Y porem o nome dessa classe Y é diferente dependo da versão. É possível estender uma classe via reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi do seu problema, você quer extender uma classe em tempo de execução (*runtime*).

Creio que você possa usar o [CGlib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib/wiki) para isto:

> cglib is a powerful, high performance and quality Code Generation
>   Library, **It is used to extend JAVA classes** and implements interfaces
>   **at runtime**.

Comment: Da uma olhada nos comentarios que botei ali em cima. Obrigado pela resposta mas provavelmente não iriei usar reflexão nesse caso. Obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

> Eu trabalho com uma API que muda o nome da classe e o nome das package sempre que uma atualização grande sai

Não, você não trabalha com uma API. APIs são estáveis. Isso é uma gambiarra que alguém que não entende o que é API chamou de API, ou nem é uma API real e você está usando como se fosse uma.

Quase todos os casos de uso de reflexão são erradas. Se você sabe o nome que precisa usar não precisa de reflexão, se não sabe não consegue fazer muita coisa útil ali. Pode imprimir tudo sem uma inteligência especial ou fazer algo muito padronizado.

Eu não sei como resolveu isso, a pergunta não deixa claro sobre como é isso, mas é quase certo que não precisa da reflexão para isso. Agora que precisa herdar em alguma outra isso fica mais claro que não é o que deseja. Agora está querendo resolver em temp ode execução algo que deve ser resolvido em tempo de compilação. Certamente existe solução, mas é uma gambiarra tão grande que é melhor não usar. Não existe um recurso específico da reflexão que cria uma extensão, mas é possível.

Eu reveria até a decisão de usar reflexão. Eu só não vou garantir que não tem uma solução melhor sem ela porque não sei nem qual é o problema, mas eu consegui eliminar toda reflexão que alguém fez até hoje, e quase todo caso era uma solução claramente melhor, as outras era discutível.

Comment: Sempre que você tem um Software você quer que seus clientes usem a versão mais atualizada certo? Então, basicamente essa "empresa" sempre que atualizar o software altera o caminho da package fazendo então com que as pessoas que usem a "API" atualizem o seu software também. Esse software atualmente esta na versão 1.13.2 porém a maioria esmagadora dos usuarios (80%) prefere a versão 1.8.8. Desta maneira ao criar meu Software usando essa API eu precisaria de reflection para fazer meu Software rodar em ambas as versões.

Comment: Eu já trabalhei muito com Reflection, inclusive, postei até um "mini-curso" com 10 aulas no YT falando sobre Reflection, nesse caso vou optar por criar 1 build para cada versão da API, eu sinceramente não gosto de fazer isso, é como se eu criasse 1 Software e o instalador do Windows7 fosse diferente do 8 e do 10... Obrigado pela respsota.

Comment: Não, nada disso faz sentido. O que certamente não tem nessas aulas é que tudo isso não é necessário, reflexão só é necessária quando depende de um usuário digitando algo e partindo disso algo no código precisa ser mudado. Fazer isso com alguma restrição continua tornando a reflexão desnecessária, se fizer se limites é altamente temerário e completamente inseguro. As pessoas usam reflexão por não conhecer outras formas de fazer, só isso. Quando a pessoa aprende outra forma ela vê não é necessário.

Comment: A programação é muito ampla e pelo que estou vendo você esta "trancado" a essa ideia de que reflexão só é útil ou necessária nesses casos que conhece. Como eu expliquei, no meu caso, eu poderia muito bem gerar 1 build do meu Software para cada versão da "API" porém eu posso simplesmente usar reflexão e gerar apenas 1 build que roda em todas as versões.

Comment: Eu desenvolvo softwares há 35 anos, já fiz todo tipo de software, estudo profundamente todas as consequências das decisões de software, conheço reflexão em todos seus detalhes por já ter criado mecanismos de reflexão e sou reconhecido por enxergar o que as pessoas não enxergam facilmente por não terem os fundamentos, e este é um caso dos mais óbvios que não precisa de reflexão porque se sabe tudo o que precisa em tempo de compilação, e eu é que estou trancado em uma ideia fixa? Ok então, eu fiz o que eu pude, lamento não ter te demovido dessa ideia, você pode fazer como achar melhor.

Comment: Acho que eu esqueci de comentar o fato que eu uso reflexão em no máximo 2 ou 3 classes, são poucos os métodos, se eu fosse gerar 1 build pra cada versão da API eu teria que criar mais de 30 builds diferentes. (1983 ?)